# Estimating extrinsic parameters in stereo vision via sensors

Tags: stereo-vision, precise-positioning, jetson

I have multiple (around 6) cameras with a distance of around 4 meters to each other filming an object and I want to reconstruct the 3D shape of it. The cameras are attached to tripods and thus can be moved around. Each camera + tripod additionally houses a Jetson Nano for image processing. The Nanos are in the same ethernet network and can reach each other.
For 3D reconstruction, I need the extrinsic parameters (R, t) of each camera relative to each other so that I can bring them into a common coordinate system.
I know that the extrinsic parameters can be estimated by correspondence search but I don't want to do that. I want to estimate R and t via sensors which I can connect to the Jetson Nanos (preferably via USB). So my idea is that each Jetson Nano has some kind of position sensor which sends their location to the other Nanos.

Do any sensors exist which can do that? I am a total beginner in robotics and have no clue if that is possible.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual goal that you want to achieve: being able to setup your cameras on-site in approximate positions, and have them auto-calibrate? Or being able to move the cameras at runtime? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your question. In fact both. I want to position camera 1 first as reference frame. The position of this camera will be fixed. And then position the other cameras and let them auto-calibrate relative to camera 1. And then I want to move them around and re-calibrate.

Comment: Then why not place some known object at the centre, easily recognisable by each camera (e.g. with markers) and have the cameras identify their relative pose using that object as their common reference?

Comment: That's a reasonable question. Because the cameras will be placed on a football pitch, filming football players during training. I am reluctant to add an additional complexity layer with markers. It would be more convenient to estimate the position data via sensors and send them around. If that's impossible then I really have to calibrate via vision.